# Values from DB not displaying in PloneFormGen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I have followed SteveM's How-To on [SQL CRUD with PloneFormGen](http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen/documentation/tutorial/sql-crud). The form has 3 string fields:
`uid`, `string1` and `string2`.
   I'm able to write data to the database via the example form and all the Z methods test ok in the ZMI.  However, the formSetup script is not working as I expected.

Here's the fromSetup script

```py
request = container.REQUEST
form = request.form

if form.has_key('uid') and not form.has_key('form.submitted') :
    res = context.testReadRow().dictionaries()
    if len(res) == 0:

container.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(context.portal_url()+'/add-new-employee')
    else:
        row = res[0]
        for key in row.keys():
            form[key] = row[key]
```

Passing, via URL, a uid that IS NOT in the database, correctly redirects to add-new-employee form.

Passing a uid that IS in the database, populates the uid text box with the value passed,  but string1 and string2 text boxes are empty.

How do I get the values from testReadRow to show as the defaults in string1 and string2?
Am I missing something?